# Is there any Forum or Knowledge base for Plumtree interms of hosting Asp.net as Portlets

Tags: asp.net, ajax, plumtree

I am quite new to Plumtree, and hosting asp.net pages as portlets is not so easy.

There are weird issues coming up every time, like

-> Session variables don't work across PAges
-> Build- in Ajax doesn;t work
-> Response.redirect fails

I would like know more on hosting asp.net pages in plumtree, Please let me know if you come across any  Forum or Knowledge base for Plumtree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best place would be BEA/Oracle forums for Aqualogic, LiquidSomething, Interaction, or whatever they call it now.

Explaining inner-working of Plumtree here would take forever.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the session preference in the web service definition
B

Answer (score 0):

Use session preferences.  More information and details can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13174_01/alui/devdoc/docs60/Portlets/Basics/PlumtreeDevDoc_Integration_Portlets_Settings.htm

Also check out http://www.function1.com/blog for Plumtree/Aqualogic Interaction/WebCenter Interaction discussion.